# How to load Microsoft file like docx in swift via UIWebView

Tags: swift, uiwebview, iosdeployment

I have been working on ios app which now i am facing some problems. I want to load some files like `docx, xls` using `UIWebView`. It gets me white screen on my actual device.

```
@IBOutlet weak var fileServerWebView: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "easychair", ofType: "docx"){
        let targetUrl: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let request = URLRequest(url: targetUrl as URL)
        fileServerWebView.delegate = self
        fileServerWebView.scalesPageToFit = true
        fileServerWebView.loadRequest(request)
    }else{
        print("cannot get path")
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

That is code that i tried to load that file from local. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use *WKWebView* instead.

Comment: @VisalSambo I tried your code, it worked fine with docx and xlsx. Check whether your path is nil?

Comment: @ToseefKhilji i will try sir. thank you

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari I have tried it again and it return me `null` but when i try to open another file like `pdf` it works fine. i feel like `UIWebView` is not available for `Microsoft file`.